# how to group data from a column into rows based on content

Tags: excel, transpose

In Excel, I have a column of filenames. Each filename as a unique prefix and I would like to transpose all cells in the column with matching prefix into a unique row. There is not a fixed number of entries with matching prefixes, as I have seen a solution with that condition.

For example, I have data in a column like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple_1 |  |  |
| Apple_2 |  |  |
| Apple_3 |  |  |
| Boy_1 |  |  |
| Cow_1 |  |  |
| Cow_2 |  |  |

and I want to group and transpose it into rows like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple_1 | Apple_2 | Apple_3 |
| Boy_1 |  |  |
| Cow_1 | Cow_2 |  |

I think I can do it in VBA, but was hoping there is some way to do this without custom coding.

EDIT - Basically, this is what I need to do in a VBA macro:

```
FoundCnt = 0
CurrentCell = A1
Get the string of chars up until the _ and store in CurrentPrefix 
Do {
    NextCell = CurrentCell +1
    Get the chars in NextCell up until the _  
    store in NextPrefix
    If CurrentPrefix == NextPrefix {
        move content of NextCell up 1 and to the right to B FoundCnt + 1
        FoundCnt++
        delete Row containing NextCell
    } else {
        FoundCnt = 0
    }
    CurrentCell = NextCell
}  Until NextCell == ""
```

Comment: What do you mean by "custom coding"?  It'll be easiest and most flexible in VBA or Power Query. You could probably do it with formulas with a bunch of helper columns. If you have trouble, edit your question to include your code and your problems.

Comment: i just wanted to see if there was some sort of built in data functions such as the Transpose, Grouping, etc. before I spend a bunch of time in VBA. It has been a while since I used that.

Comment: Do you have a list of all the prefixes, or is there  a simple rule like taking the first two letters of the data?

Comment: The prefixes are all different but typically of the format ACC-0001_something.jpg

Comment: The prefixes are all different but typically of the format "ACC-0001_something.jpg" and "ACC-0001_somethingelse.jpg" so the ACC-0001_ prefix is how to match. The next chunk would be "SEAT-0001_random1.jpg" and "SEAT_0001_random2.jpg", etc. The matching of data in the columns is the first 6-10 chars until the _ There could be one entry with the prefix_ or more, but they are al least all sorted in the column to be in consecutive cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plz try this - it isn't very different from the formula for converting a single column into a 2d range with a fixed number of columns, you just hang the output on a Sequence with number of rows equal to number of unique prefixes and number of columns equal to max number of entries sharing the same prefix. Then you have to check that the current output column is less than the number of entries matching the current prefix:

```
=LET(range,A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)),
uniques,UNIQUE(LEFT(range,FIND("_",range))),
cols,MAX(COUNTIF(range,uniques&"*")),
seq,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(uniques),cols,0),
IF(MOD(seq,cols)<COUNTIF(range,uniques&"*"),INDEX(range,MATCH(INDEX(uniques,INT(seq/cols)+1)&"*",range,0)+MOD(seq,cols)),""))
```

[image]

Comment: That is great! Thank you so much Tom.