# Google Sheets - combine data from multiple rows to single row or cell with arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have an export from our student information system that has multiple rows for each student, depending on how many contact email addresses the parent entered.

[Sample data from the export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SG0W.png)

I would like to combine all the contact addresses either into multiple columns on the same row or even all to the same cell would be fine. After many attempts through a lot of searching, I can get it to work with =join(char(10), filter(extract.csv!G:G,extract.csv!A:A=J2)) and manually filling the formula down. (Although I'd rather not have the return first but rather just between the results, but I can live with it if it's not possible.)

What'd I'd love is to have that in an arrayformula so that I don't have to copy it down but I can't figure out how to adjust the last reference to the J row. If I leave it as is, it puts the same values in every cell to match the J2 data.

[with arrayformula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7S16.png)

Or is there another way to get what I'm trying for? Thanks for any help... I'm just a teacher who loves to code and automate things muddling through and learning bits and pieces as I go!

Comment: This can be done, but it is complex. The most efficient way to receive help would be to share a link to a sample spreadsheet set up exactly as you show in your images. (You only have dummy data, no sensitive data, so that is no issue.) Sharing access to the sample spreadsheet will allow access to actual data as well as a testing ground and place to leave a solution. Just be sure when you create the link to set the Share permission to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor," so that those here can access the sheet fully.

Comment: Yes it is quite tricky. I've done a similar thing in Excel here, if you would like to get an idea of it, so one approach would be to re-do this as a Google Sheets formula https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67504794/how-to-group-data-from-a-column-into-rows-based-on-content/67510732#67510732

Comment: BTW if you can put an upper limit on the number of email addresses a student might have, it would make it a little bit easier. Also I should have said welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thanks @ErikTyler Here's a sample spreadsheet with edit access. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LSIIDQrVD6lV8ovU7TkxLFAlw6-YnsmiCP4QHHWazsI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm glad to know it's complex since it was giving me so much trouble! I'll experiment with the Excel solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably worth posting this, because it's how far I got just creating some representative data of my own before I realised that you'd posted a sheet for us (thank you).

```
=ArrayFormula(if(mod(sequence(countunique(A2:A),D2,0),D2)<countif(A2:A,unique(filter(A2:A,A2:A<>""))),
vlookup(vlookup(unique(filter(A2:A,A2:A<>"")),{A2:A,row(A2:A)},2,false)+MOD(sequence(COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A),D2,0),D2),{row(A2:A),B2:B},2,false),))
```

D2 is a helper cell which contains the maximum number of contacts per student - either from formula or entered manually.

[image]

I will have a go with your data, but I wasn't quite clear whether the student's own email should come first, followed by the parent contacts? I'm kind of hoping that the secondary email isn't populated because it would complicate things further.

Here's how it looks with your data - same formula with slightly different columns:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(mod(sequence(countunique(A2:A),I2,0),I2)<countif(A2:A,unique(filter(A2:A,A2:A<>""))), vlookup(vlookup(unique(filter(A2:A,A2:A<>"")),{A2:A,row(A2:A)},2,false)+MOD(sequence(COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A),I2,0),I2),{row(A2:A),G2:G},2,false),))
```

where I2 is currently set to 5 - it can be worked out from

```
=max(countif(A2:A,unique(filter(A2:A,A2:A<>""))))
```

if you want to make it more dynamic.

[image]

The issue being that I can't think of an easy way to remove the blank email address for the first student at the moment (I'm a bit surprised that the download contains blank addresses - data quality?).

Answer (score 0):

I have added a new sheet ("Erik Help"), which is a duplicate of your "AutoFillData" sheet. In my sheet, I cleared Column AD and then placed the following formula in AD1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Contact Emails";IF(J2:J="",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J2:J,{UNIQUE(FILTER(extract.csv!A2:A,extract.csv!A2:A<>"")),SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(FILTER(extract.csv!A2:A,extract.csv!A2:A<>""))&"*"&TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER("|"&{extract.csv!E2:E;extract.csv!F2:F;extract.csv!G2:G},{extract.csv!E2:E;extract.csv!F2:F;extract.csv!G2:G}<>"")))&"*",extract.csv!A2:A&"|"&extract.csv!E2:E&"|"&extract.csv!F2:F&"|"&extract.csv!G2:G,1,FALSE)),,TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER({extract.csv!E2:E;extract.csv!F2:F;extract.csv!G2:G},{extract.csv!E2:E;extract.csv!F2:F;extract.csv!G2:G}<>"")))))," ",COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER({extract.csv!E2:E;extract.csv!F2:F;extract.csv!G2:G},{extract.csv!E2:E;extract.csv!F2:F;extract.csv!G2:G}<>""))))))," ",CHAR(10))},2,FALSE)))})'

Explaining this formula fully would take quite a long time.

In general, what it does is form a virtual 2D grid (never seen by the user) with the unique list of student IDs running vertically at left and the unique list of all email addresses (with an appended delineator) running horizontally across the top. If the *combination* of student ID and that email address is found in any string formed by the mash-up of studentID|email1|email2|email3, then that email address fills the virtual grid; if not, then that cross-section of the grid is left null.

This leaves a grid where all possible emails are filled in horizontally somewhere across from each unique ID, rather than being on separate lines.

Finally, a quirk in the `QUERY` function is used to combine all non-null entries per row. That is, the `QUERY` function can have any number of headers, not just 0 or 1. By having `QUERY` request every email section of the grid as headers and then `TRIM`ing out spaces, we wind up with all the emails for each student ID together.

Then it's just a matter of replacing the remaining spaces with a line return character, i.e., CHAR(10).

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few solutions (in sheets **kishkin 1** in **kishkin 2** respectively).

Emails in one row in separate columns:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(
    J2:J = "",,
      TRIM(
        SPLIT(
          VLOOKUP(
            J2:J,
            SPLIT(
              TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
                QUERY(
                  FILTER({extract.csv!A:A & "♥", extract.csv!G:G & "♦"}, extract.csv!A:A <> ""),
                  "SELECT MAX(Col2)
                   GROUP BY Col2
                   PIVOT Col1",
                  1
                ),, COUNTA(extract.csv!A:A)
              )),
              "♥"
            ),
            2,
          ),
          "♦"
        )
      )
  )
)
```

[image]

Emails in a single cell:

```
={
  "CONTACT EMAILS";
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(
      J2:J = "",,
        REGEXREPLACE(
          VLOOKUP(
            J2:J,
            SPLIT(
              TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
                QUERY(
                  FILTER({extract.csv!A:A & "♥", extract.csv!G:G & CHAR(10)}, extract.csv!A:A <> ""),
                  "SELECT MAX(Col2)
                   GROUP BY Col2
                   PIVOT Col1",
                  1
                ),, COUNTA(extract.csv!A:A)
              )),
              "♥"
            ),
            2,
          ),
          "(?m)^\s+|\s+$",
        )
    )
  )
}
```

[image]